# Как добавить к высоте документа несколько px?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как добавить к высоте документа несколько px?

```
$(function() {
    var iframe = $('#iframe', parent.document.body);
    iframe.height($(document.body).height());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var iframe = $('#iframe', parent.document.body);
    iframe.height($(document.body).height() + 10);
});
```